# git pull origin master via VSTS Rest API

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to merge two branches using [visual studio team services API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview).

In other words, I have a branch features/feature1 and I would like to execute "git pull origin master" in that branch? 
Can I do that using the API without going through a pull request?

Also, in case there are merge conflicts, can I resolve them by simply choosing source or target version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such REST API to merge two branches or execute `git pull` command since git commands can be execute directly or by calling some functions (no matter for command line, powershell or C# etc).

You can run `git pull` command for your code as the way how git commands executed.

And when execute `git pull` command and to solve the merge conflicts automatically by adding `-X` options:

- Choose source (`features/feature1` branch) version: `git pull origin master -X theirs`
- Choose target (`master` branch) version: `git pull origin master -X ours`

Comment: Thanks, I know how do it locally, but for the purpose of automating some of our processes, I needed to merge two branches via rest api :) I'll go with a pull request then.